# Pyside: Updating icons when changing the themeSearchPaths()

Tags: python, qt, themes, frontend, pyside

I'm currently trying to enable switching the icon theme of an application during runtime.

The problem is that I just cant figure out how to trigger the objects to "refresh" their icons and pick them from the new `QIcon.themeSearchPaths()`.

```
def change_icon(self):
    style = QApplication.style()

    if self.standart_icon_theme_active:
        QIcon.setThemeSearchPaths([""]) # resetting to the 'default' folder
        QIcon.setThemeName(u"")
    else:
        QIcon.setThemeSearchPaths(["icons/"]) # the folder with my icons
        QIcon.setThemeName(u"icons")

    for btn in self.bttns:
        btn.setIcon(style.standardIcon(getattr(QStyle, btn.objectName()))) # <= im searching for a signal or something to replace this 

    self.standart_icon_theme_active = not self.standart_icon_theme_active
```

What I currently have is a little demo Window with a lot of buttons, (which got created with a list of names of icons, so that their name equals the icon they have) in which each icon of each button gets updated when `change_icon()` gets triggered, and i'm searching for something like a builtin signal which I can emit to let Pyside update each icon on its own, or something in that way.

Any help would be appreciated.